# JS, return something friendly than undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a dictionary object in javascript (eg associate array)

```
var myobj = {
  "a" : "Some string",
  "b" : "Some string else"
}
```

if I access myobj.a, it will return "Some string"
but if I access something not in the list myobj.c it return undefined.
Is there any way to set object getter to return something like: "Key not available"
Can we use prototype...
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes/No.

### No

There is no way to intercept generic get's on keys using ES5

### Yes

#### Use methods

```
var Dictionary = {
    get: function (key) {
        if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(this, key)) {
            return this[key]
        }
        return "Key not available"
    }
}
```

Note there are some pitfalls using objects as dictionary, consider using a module like [strmap](https://github.com/rauschma/strmap)

#### Use ES6 proxies (not implemented in browsers)

Using an [ES6 proxy](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adirect_proxies)

```
var dictionary = Proxy({}, {
    get: function (target, name) {
        if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(target, name)) {
            return target[name
        }
        return "Key not available"
    }
})
```

#### Using an ES6 Map (shimmable)

Just use an [ES6 map](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3asimple_maps_and_sets)

```
var dict = new Map
dict.set("foo", "bar")
dict.get("foo")
```

Comment: Chrome 18 has a flag by the way. =D And firefox has had Proxies for a while. The time is coming!

Comment: @benvie still not implemented because im using the direct proxy API ;)

Comment: I use the shim for everything. I just published two knew awesome direct proxy related things last night. You should take a look =D https://github.com/Benvie/easy-proxy I normalized the traps and combined them down to 8 total traps, with most of the code needed in just 4 traps: get, set, list, invoke.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to create a wrapper method that tests if the key exists first and if not returns your standard text.

e.g.

```
// ... in your object definition, depending on how you have done it
get: function(key) {
    if (key in this) {
        return this[key];
    } else {
        return 'Key not available.';
    }
}
```

Then just use it: `a.get('c')`.

Comment: the `in` operator returns true for keys defined in prototypes and is thus unsafe

Comment: @Raynos True. Your answer is definitely more detailed. It's actually annoying there is no nice dynamic way of handling undefined methods/properties in Javascript like there is in other dynamic languages like Ruby. Oh well, you work with what you have, right?

Comment: Just write a JS preprocessor that implements direct proxies